# Django 4.x - Conditional QuerySet for Pagination and a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Disclaimer:** *I have searched and a question tackling this particular challenge could not be found at the time of posting.*

### The Requirement

For a Class Based View I need to implement Pagination for a QuerySet derived through a many to many relationship. Here's the requirement with a more concrete description:

- Many Library Records can belong to many Collections
- Web pages are required for most (but not necessarily all) Collections, and so I need to build views/templates/urls based on what the client identifies as required
- Each Collection Page displaying the relevant Library Records requires Pagination, as there may be 100's of records to display.

### The First Approach

And so with this requirement in mind I approached this as I normally would when building a CBV with Pagination. However, this approach did not allow me to meet the requirement. What I quickly discovered was that the Pagination method in the CBV was building the object based on the declared model, but the many to many relationship was not working for me.

I explored the use of object in the template, but after a number of attempts I was getting nowhere. I need to display Library Record objects but the many to many relationship demands that I do so after determining the records based on the Collection they belong to.

### EDIT - Addition of model

`models.py`

```
class CollectionOrder(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        Collection,
        related_name='collection_in_collection_order',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Collection'
    )
    record = models.ForeignKey(
        LibraryRecord,
        related_name='record_in_collection_order',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Library record',
    )
    order_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

Comment: Can you please share your models. Especially the `related_name` is interesting, since it can minimize the number of queries.

Answer (score 2):

Please do *not* work with `record.record.id`: this will each time make a query for *each* `CollectionOrder` object, and thus if there are 100 `CollectionOrder` objects, that will make 100 extra queries, and thus eventually make 102 queries. If the number of matches is thus quite large, it will eventually no longer respond (within reasonable time).

Furthermore `pk__in=library_records_ids` will *not* respect the order of the `library_record_ids`. Indeed, it can return the `LibraryRecord`s in any order, as long as these have primary keys that are members of the list.

You can query with:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return LibraryRecord.objects.filter(
        collectionorder__collection__collection='collection-name'
    ).order_by('collectionorder__order_number')
```

Where *`collectionorder`* is the [**`related_query_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) for the `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField` or `ManyToManyField` named `record` from `CollectionOrder` to the `LibraryRecord` model. If you did not specify a value for the `related_query_name=…` parameter, it will take the value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), and if you did not specify that one either, it will use the name of the source model (so where the relation is *defined*) in lowercase, so in this case `collectionorder`.

This will thus respect  the `collectionorder__order_number` as ordering condition, and perform this in a *single* database query, minimizing the amount of queries to the database.

Comment: I just deployed that suggested code and I'm getting an error. I'll dig in. I want this optimization to work, but it will apparently take some deeper digging. I think I can see what is happening. My existing model design doesn't store collectionorder in the LibraryRecords model. This is established in the CollectionOrder model. I will keep exploring this...To be fair, I didn't post my model schema either.

Comment: @Carewen: what is the error you get?

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'collectionorder' into field. Choices are: benediction, date_communicated, date_created, discourse_series, discourse_series_id, doc_url, id, invocation, language, library_record_type, mp3_url, part_number, pdf_url, principal_cosmic_author, principal_cosmic_author_id, record_in_collection_order, record_in_reading_progress, supporting_cosmic_authors, tags, text, title`

Comment: @Carewen: likely you have set a `related_name` in the `record = ForeignKey(related_name=...)`, you then need to replace `collectionorder__` with `related_name_value__` with `related_name_value` the value for the `related_name=...` parameter, as specified in the paragraph after the code fragment.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a great learning exercise. I will update my original answer with the optimized code. This really was a great learning experience for me on a number of levels, and thanks to your time my answer won't be poorly done. It worked, but it is now better.

Answer (score 0):

*Hopefully, this Q&A helps someone else. If in reading the following approach you can think of ways to refactor/optimize I'd love to learn. Note: I deliberately did not implement Pythonic List Comprehension for my personal preference of readability.*

What I ended up doing was adding `get_queryset()` to:

- Query the Collection for the records belong to it, to then
- Build a list of record ids, to then
- Return the QuerySet by filtering for `pk__in` (the pk exists in the list of library_record_ids)

Here's the resulting code.  (Edit: This code has been optimized following another answer - I just didn't want to leave a lesser snippet up)

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return LibraryRecord.objects.filter(
            record_in_collection_order__collection__collection='Collection Name'
        ).order_by('record_in_collection_order__order_number')
```

The requirement has been met. I welcome constructive criticism. My intention in sharing this Q&A is to try and give a little back to the Stack Overflow Community that has served me so well since starting this journey into Django.